# How to mount /system or / in a rooted device

Tags: android, testing, mount, penetration-testing, penetration-tools

How to mount the read only file system folder in Andorid 10 devices ?

I am trying to move some necessary files to /system  but i am getting allways an error .

when i run  `mv myfile/path /system`

i get the following error : `mv: /system is read-only file system`

i am with a root user and trying : `mount -o rw,remount /system`

**the Device i use is Pixel 4**

**Android version is 10**

**rooted with Magisk 20.4**

thanx